# Cannot build Unity project for HoloLens with IBM Watson SDK

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I'm having troubles building my Unity project. I tried both a custom scene, created by me, and the example scenes located into `Examples/ServiceExamples`. 
Basically, I want to take a picture with the HoloLens webcam and call IBM Watson visual recognition service. All Mixed Reality settings have been configured correctly. When I try to build the project I get lots of errors and they're all related to Watson SDK. For instance, the first error is the following:

> Assets\Watson\ThirdParty\WebSocketSharp\Ext.cs(54,36): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'X509Certificates' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Security.Cryptography' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I tried to install directly from the solution some of these packages that i'm missing, but the error remains there. Do you think it could be due to my Visual Studio project settings (e.g.: .NET targets, ecc)?
Here are my Unity settings:

[My settings imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHnkg.png)

Am I missing something else? Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a Unity package recently added for this particular need, see https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk/issues/173 I believe is not part of the official release as for now, but you can get it from GitHub.

Comment: Thank you! I really did not notice that issue on GitHub!